# Use custom container for slider thumb in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, slider

I want to use a custom container for a slider thumb in React. I know, that I can use a custom background picture or style the thumb, but i want to replace the thumb with a custom container/div. Is this possible?

I have a codepen example, that seems to do what i want to do, but somehow i can not get it to work and post the link here... The link is in the comments.

Comment: this is the link https://codepen.io/abhisharma2/pen/wMOpqz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a React slider component, that lets you replace the thumb. And it looks like the guy went through some trouble to do this, so i just use his work ;)

https://github.com/tjallen/react-simple-range